# in drupal 7, need a simple module example for ajax, json and drupal.behavior for jquery?

Tags: json, drupal, module, behavior

I have been looking for a example of module that builds a hook_menu that outputs json, and there is a jquery file that works in drupal.behavior.

could someone recommend me a example if you have it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Examples for Developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples), see ahah_example or ajax_example there.